# Updating answers to exercise question for survey

Tags: feature-request, survey

Reviewing the developer survey for 2018 and really looking into the exercise question with the response options:

- I don't typically exercise
- 1 - 2 times per week
- 3 - 4 times per week
- Daily or almost every day

These time frames can lead to lots of skewed answers for how small of a time frame a week is to measure this.

I recommend moving to a month as the unit of measurement.

- I don't typically exercise
- 5 times or less per month
- 6 - 12 times per month
- 13 - 20 times per month
- More than 20 times per month

The pair of ranges could be split into further more granular options.

There really is a big difference between I goto the gym once a week, and maybe if i'm bored on a saturday vs I goto the gym twice a week habitually, month in month out.

Comment: I think the "I don't typically exercise" should be a "Less than some lower bound" instead ("Less than once a month" or something) because I don't feel like I fit into any of the numerically defined categories, yet I _do_ typically exercise. I'd say not a year goes by when I haven't.

Comment: I do agree with @Don'tPanic, by saying 'I don't typically...', is more unlikely that anyone taking the survey will select this options just because is close to a 'I never....' or 'I always...'.